# Is it possible to target the first child of a div with CSS?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

Is it possible to target the first `.col`/`h2` and add a CSS style of `padding-top:0px`?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="holder">
        <article class="col"><h2><a href="xxx">xxxx</a></h4></article>
        <article class="col"><h2><a href="xxx">xxxx</a></h4></article>
        <article class="col"><h2><a href="xxx">xxxx</a></h4></article>
        <article class="col"><h2><a href="xxx">xxxx</a></h4></article>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is asking about **possibilities** and **is not a concrete coding question**. If you want to know if something is possible you should **research it** and **attempt to implement it**. If you have issues while doing this you then can ask a **specific** question, **showing the code you have written**, your expected results, and your actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Use `:first-child`:

```
.col:first-child h2 {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

> [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3afirst-child)
>
> The `:first-child` CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out and it works. I just wasn't sure because I tried it out before posting here if using :first-child only applied to lists.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pseudo-class `:first-child` to accomplish that.

```
.container .holder article:first-child {
padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Also, just a heads up, you are closing your `<h2>` tag with an `</h4>`.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t7RR2/)

**pseudo-class :first-child**

```
.col h2:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```